# React native state change transitions

Tags: animation, react-native, transition

What is the best pattern, in react native, to animate components on state change?

For example I have a list of elements and tapping on one I want it to disappear and the ones below him to 'get up' filling the missing space

How can I make the transition smooth?

Answer (score 2):

React-natives own [animated API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html) works really well.

Basically you have a value in state, which you connect with a style props, and change that value over time. (for examples follow link)

For smooth animations use `usenativedriver` (not always possible) and also, make sure you don't have debugger runnning in emulated/real device

> EDIT: 2018-05-31

*This is an example of how I've used it. Probably exist other ways of doing it*

```
import { Animated, Text} from 'react-native';

class ShowCaseAnimation extends Component {

  state = { 
    animations: {
      height: new Animated.Value(0),
      fade: new Animated.Value(0),
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { height, fade } = this.state.animations;
    if (this.props.animate) {
      doneAnimation({ height, fade }).start(() => {
        // Do stuff after animations
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { animations } = this.state; 
    return (
      <Animated.View 
        style={{
          height: animate? animations.height : 300, 
          opacity: animate? animations.fade: 1,
          // other styling 
        }}
      >
        <Text> All your base are belong to us </Text>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

*doneAnimation: *

```
import { Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';

export const doneAnimation = ({ height, fade }) => Animated.parallel([
  Animated.timing(height, {
    toValue: 300,
    easing: Easing.elastic(),
    duration: 500,
    delay: 1500,
  }),
  Animated.timing(fade, {
    toValue: 1,
    easing: Easing.ease,
    duration: 1000,
    delay: 1500,
  }),
]);

export default doneAnimation;
```

**doneAnimation** will change the state and perform the described animations.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What I was meaning is: how should I handle everything? Should I hide the element before updating status and moving up all other elements, using FLIP, etc etc? componentWillReceiveProps() and componentWillUpdate() have been marked unsafe, what I was asking for is a safe pattern to implement

Comment: Not sure what you mean by moving up all other elements. I updated my answer with an example how I use it :) Is it to any help ?

Comment: You are showing how to animated somwthing, but I cannot see any animation triggered by a state change in your example

Comment: this.setState({}, () => this.myAnimation())
use setStates callback

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can trigger an animation on state change in a functional component.

Say you have a Button that changes state with onPress:

```
<Button title="toggle" onPress={() => setValue(!Value)} />
```

then you can trigger the animation inside a useEffect with the Value
that changes in the dependency array:

```
const [Value, setValue] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    // Input your animation here
    // ...
  }, [Value]);
```